# Sample code for file-picker in Xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, xamarin.mobile

Can anyone show me how to implement a file-chooser/picker for Android using Mono?

Thanks in advance,
Tery

Comment: Did you search for an example on the internet yet?

Comment: I've searched far and wide for an example.  Literally spent a whole day trying to find something.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this [sample work](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/files/browse_files) for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use one of the Xamarin Plugin projects available as a NuGet package, if you want to support more platforms later. The currently most actively maintained package is this one:
https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows
(note: I'm one of the contributors to the project).

Picking files is as easy as calling `var result = await PickFile()` and checking the result object. See also the sample code mentioned in the README.md of the Github project.